# javax.ejb.EJBException when persisting an entity

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, entitymanager

I have an entity called *Medico* which was created as an Entity Class from Database, hence I think the entity definition is failsafe here, nevertheless the definition is the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "medico")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({All named queries here})
public class Medico implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "idMedico")
    private Integer idMedico;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Identificacion")
    private int identificacion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 33)
    @Column(name = "Primer_Nombre")
    private String primerNombre;
    @Size(max = 33)
    @Column(name = "Segundo_Nombre")
    private String segundoNombre;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 33)
    @Column(name = "Primer_Apellido")
    private String primerApellido;
    @Size(max = 33)
    @Column(name = "Segundo_Apellido")
    private String segundoApellido;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Telefono")
    private long telefono;
    @Column(name = "Telefono_Celular")
    private BigInteger telefonoCelular;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 33)
    @Column(name = "Direccion")
    private String direccion;
    // Constructors..
    // Getters and setters..
}
```

I want to create new *Medico* entities on MySql database, and this is how I am doing so:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ConsultaMedicos implements Serializable {
// Variables Definition ..
@EJB
private DoctorsFacadeLocal doctorsFacade; 
// Constructor and other methods ..
public String save()
    {
        try{
            doctorsFacade.save(consultedDoctor);
            FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, CREATE_SUMMARY, null);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(CREATE_SUMMARY, fm);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, CREATE_ERROR_SUMMARY, null);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(CREATE_ERROR_SUMMARY, fm);
            return null;
        }
        return "listaMedicos.xhtml";
    }
...
}
```

---

```
@Local
public interface DoctorsFacadeLocal {

    List<Medico> findAllDoctors();
    Medico findDoctorByIdNumber(int identificacion);
    void edit(Medico medico);
    void save(Medico medico);
}
```

---

```
@Stateless
public class DoctorsFacade implements DoctorsFacadeLocal {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
// Other methods.. 
    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void save(Medico medico)
    {
        em.persist(medico);
        em.flush();
    }
}
```

---

After I call `save()` from my JSF page, I get the following exception:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5194)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5092)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4880)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2039)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1990)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at $Proxy157.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.lemm.web.bean.ConsultaMedicos.save(ConsultaMedicos.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:737)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:467)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:228)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.validateOnCallbackEvent(BeanValidationListener.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.prePersist(BeanValidationListener.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyListener(DescriptorEventManager.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyEJB30Listeners(DescriptorEventManager.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.executeEvent(DescriptorEventManager.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectClone(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4216)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.cloneAndRegisterNewObject(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalRegisterObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2883)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.registerObjectForMergeCloneIntoWorkingCopy(MergeManager.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfCloneIntoWorkingCopy(MergeManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.mergeCloneWithReferences(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3467)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.mergeCloneWithReferences(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.mergeCloneWithReferences(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3427)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.mergeInternal(EntityManagerImpl.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.merge(EntityManagerImpl.java:429)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.merge(EntityManagerWrapper.java:286)
    at com.lemm.ejb.facade.DoctorsFacade.save(DoctorsFacade.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5367)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:801)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:862)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:801)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:371)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5339)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5327)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    ... 47 more
```

---

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?
If it serves for anything heres my persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="lemmPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/lemmdb</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: I can edit existing entities with the current persistence unit using `em.merge`, however I can not create as the question is stating

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exception clearly states that there is a constraint validation violation. I assume you have a pre persist interceptor in the class that defines the type of the consultedDoctor that you are trying to save. 
Look there and provide some further info about the type of the class and the pre persist interceptor, as well as the mapping and constraints of the Medico entity beans.

Kind regards

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I added the class definition for 'Medico' which is the entity I am trying to save. However, I don't know what a _pre-persist interceptor_ is, where is it usually located or defined?

Comment: ok as I suspected, u have a lot of validations in your entity bean which is good. You don't have a specific PrePersist interceptor. To learn more about PrePersist u can check out the @PrePersist annotation and its specification.
Anyway, to solve your problem, u have to check which of the constraints is violated. I bet u have a field with a @NotNull annotation which is null or a string which is shorter than 1 or longer than 33 characters or similar. U can **debug** your code or simply print the object out before you save it and it shall make it clearer where exactly the problem is.

Comment: The problem was having a `@NotNull` set up on the entity's primary key. Removing this annotation and keeping all the other validations make the persist work, pretty obvius yet silly mistake. You pointed me in the direction to find out the problem so I am awarding the +100 right away. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks! I am glad that you resolved the problem. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 3):

In case you have an entity with an auto-incremented Id and you want to persist it using JPA using its empty constructor then the persistence context throws validation error in PrePersist stage. Remember the the auto incremented no is generated at postPersist Stage, so it validates the entity as violation of null constraint  This happens because we have specified validation strategy in our persistence unit as **auto**. Change this validation strategy as **NONE** as given under

```
    <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"      
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com 
    /xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="studPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/mysql</jta-data-source>
   <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
   <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
   <properties>
   <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
   <property name="eclipselink.weaving.fetchgroups" value="false"/>
   </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

save the persistence unit and redeploy your app. Now it wont throw any validation error as the responsibility of validation lies with you.

Answer (score 2):

This question helped me solve this problem after too many hours of beating my head against the wall.  @peshkira is spot on but had the following code been provided it may have saved me some time.  Run validation on an entity to expose failing constraint(s).

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Medico>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(medico);
if(constraintViolations.size() > 0){
    Iterator<ConstraintViolation<Medico>> iterator = constraintViolations.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        ConstraintViolation<Medico> cv = iterator.next();
        System.out.println(cv.getMessage());
        System.out.println(cv.getPropertyPath());
    }
 }
```

My problem turned out to be existing records in database that after found could not pass the entity validation.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are developing in Netbeans you may get this error through a a bit of a mix-up because Netbeans creates two copies of persistence.xml file. One of them you tend to put in META-INF in classpath, the other stays in Netbeans' Configuration Files directory. On the app start up by Netbeans (by pressing the green start triangle) the copy from META-INF is used but if you 'clean and build' the project the copy from Configuration Files directory is used. If they differ the hell breaks loose.

Comment: Not related to the circumstances given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

if the help provided above couldnt help, please check that your servlet is getting the right parameter in your jsp page.

make sure that String name =response.getParameter("Name"); (in servlet file) there exist a parameter "Name" in jsp file.  if there exist none,tring name is set to null, and null can't be inserted in a field that is marked with not null.

From personal experience.