# How to persist two entities with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, javabeans

I am using the JPA in my webapp and I can't figure out how to persist two new entities that relate to each other. Here an example:

### These are the two entities

```
+-----------------+   +--------------------+
|     Consumer    |   |   ProfilePicture   |
+-----------------+   +--------------------+
| id    (PK)      |---| consumerId (PPK+FK)|
| userName        |   | url                |
+-----------------+   +--------------------+
```

The **Consumer** has an **id** and some other values. The **ProfilePicture** uses the **Consumer**'s *id* as it's own primary key and as foreign key. (Since a ProfilePicture will not exist without a Consumer and not every Consumer has a ProfilePicture)

I used NetBeans to generate the entity classes and the session beans (facades).

### This is how they look like in short

**Consumer.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Consumer")
@NamedQueries({...})
public class Consumer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "userName")
    private String userName;     

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "consumer")
    private ProfilePicture profilePicture;

    /* and all the basic getters and setters */
    (...)
}
```

**ProfilePicture.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ProfilePicture")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({...})
public class ProfilePicture implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "consumerId")
    private Integer consumerId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "url")
    private String url;

    @JoinColumn(name = "consumerId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Consumer consumer;

    /* and all the basic getters and setters */
    (...)
}
```

So when I want to create a **Consumer** with his **ProfilePicture** I thought I would do it like this:

```
   ProfilePicture profilePicture = new ProfilePicture("http://www.url.to/picture.jpg");  // create the picture object
   Consumer consumer = new Consumer("John Doe"); // create the consumer object

   profilePicture.setConsumer(consumer);        // set the consumer in the picture (so JPA can take care about the relation      
   consumerFacade.create(consumer);             // the facade classes to persist the consumer
   profilePictureFacade.create(profilePicture);  // and when the consumer is persisted (and has an id) persist the picture
```

### My Problem

I tried almost everything in every combination but JPA doesn't seem to be able to link the two entities on it's own. Most of the time I am getting errors like this:

```
 EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB ConsumerFacade, method: public void com.me.db.resources.bean.ConsumerFacade.create(com.mintano.backendclientserver.db.resources.entity.Consumer)
 (...) 
Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
```

As far as I understand the problem, it is because the **ProfilePicture** doesn't know the id of the **Consumer** and thus, the entities cannot persist.

The only way it ever worked, was when persisting the **Consumer** first, setting it's id to the **ProfilePicture** and then persisting the picture:

```
   ProfilePicture profilePicture = new ProfilePicture("http://www.url.to/picture.jpg");  // create the picture object
   Consumer consumer = new Consumer("John Doe"); // create the consumer object

   consumerFacade.create(consumer);             // the facade classes to persist the consumer
   profilePicture.setConsumerId(consumer.getId()); // set the consumer's new id in the picture     

   profilePictureFacade.create(profilePicture);  // and when the consumer is persisted (and has an id) persist the picture
```

However these two tables are just an example and naturally the database is much more complex and setting the ids manually like this seems very inflexible and I am afraid of over complicating things. Especially because I can't persist all entities in one transaction (which seems very inefficient).

**Am I doing it right? Or is there another, more standard way?**

## Edit: my solution

As [FTR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/618407/ftr) suggested, one problem was the missing `id` for the **ProfilePicture** table (I used the **Consumer.id** as foreign and primary)..

The tables look like this now:

```
+-----------------+   +--------------------+
|     Consumer    |   |   ProfilePicture   |
+-----------------+   +--------------------+
| id    (PK)      |_  | id (PK)            |
| userName        | \_| consumerId (FK)    |
+-----------------+   | url                |
                      +--------------------+
```

Then [Alan Hay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1356423/alan-hay) told me to *Always encapsulate add/remove to relationships and then you can ensure correctness*, which I did:

**Consumer.java**

```
public void addProfilePicture(ProfilePicture profilePicture) {
    profilePicture.setConsumerId(this);  
    if (profilePictureCollection == null) {
        this.profilePictureCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    this.profilePictureCollection.add(profilePicture);
}
```

Since ProfilePicture has it's own id now, it became a **OneToMany** relationship, so each Consumer can now have many profile pictures. That's not what I intended at first, but I can life with it :) Therefore I can't just set a ProfilePicture to the Consumer but have to add it to a collection of Pictures (as above).

This was the only additional method I implemented and now it works. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: If I see it correctly ProfilePicture does not have an autogenerated ID, so unless you set one explicitly, this ought to fail. Is separating the primary and the foreign key an option?

Comment: @ftr: I just tried to give ProfilePicture it's own primary key. And I end up with a `Collection` of ProfilePictures for each consumer.. which is not that bad – even though I know it will always be max one picture per consumer. And it seems to work when calling `profilePicture.setConsumerId(consumer);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When persisting an instance of the non-owning side of the relationship (that which contains the 'mappedBy' and in your case Consumer) then you must **always** ensure both sides of the relationship are set to have cascading work as expected.

You should of course always do this anyway to ensure your domain model is correct.

```
Consumer c = new Consumer();
ProfilePicure p = new ProfilePicture();
c.setProfilePicture(p);//see implementation
//persist c
```

**Consumer.java**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Consumer")
    @NamedQueries({...})
    public class Consumer implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Integer id;

        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
        @Column(name = "userName")
        private String userName;     

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "consumer")
        private ProfilePicture profilePicture;

        public void setProfilePicture(ProfilePicture profilePicture){
            //SET BOTH SIDES OF THE RELATIONSHIP
            this.profilePicture = profilePicture;
            profilePicture.setConsumer(this);
        }
}
```

Always encapsulate add/remove to relationships and then you can ensure correctness:

```
public class Parent{
private Set<Child> children;

public Set<Child> getChildren(){
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(children); //no direct access:force clients to use add/remove methods
}

public void addChild(Child child){
    child.setParent(this); 
    children.add(child);
}

public class Child(){
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's definitely the right direction :) So I added a primary key for `ProfilePicture` as "ftr" told me and added an `addProfilePicture()` method to `Consumer` as you suggested. Now I feel comfortable with this solution. I create the `Consumer` and the `ProfilePicture` and just call `consumer.addProfilePicture(profilePicture)` and both entities get inserted as they should be!

Answer (score 0):

You can persist one object and its child at a time. So I think this should work:

```
ProfilePicture profilePicture = new ProfilePicture("http://www.url.to/picture.jpg");  // create the picture object
Consumer consumer = new Consumer("John Doe"); // create the consumer object
consumer.setProfilePicture(profilePicture); 
consumerFacade.create(consumer);
```

Comment: I just tested it and all I get is the `javax.ejb.EJBException`:...`while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'` again. And curious: not even the **Consumer** gets inserted into the database. Do you know why the `prePersist` is happening? I mean it is even set to `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`

Comment: Ok got your issue. You can remove @NotNull in ProfilePicture for  @Column(name = "consumerId") private Integer consumerId; and try it out. Since NotNull will check consumerId for this. This linke might help you [EJBException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389056/javax-ejb-ejbexception-when-persisting-an-entity)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried removing the @NotNull but unfortunately the error is still there. I think it is because the `consumerId` column in my database is set to be `NOT NULL` since it is the key for this table. But when I change the table indices as "ftr" mentioned, JPA seems to be able to understand the relation between the two tables.

Comment: Ok thats great. Nice to hear that. Thank you.