# Multiple foreign keys in one mapping class Hibernate+JPA+Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 classes called Client and Movie. I want to have a class RentedMovie that would hold foreign key of a Client and the foreign key of a Book and it would also have its own id. So far my classes look the same:

Client:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Client")
public class Client implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id", nullable= false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="age", nullable = false)
    private Integer age;

    @Column(name="numberofrentals", nullable = false)
    private Integer numberofrentals;

    @Column(name="name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="address", nullable = false)
    private String address;

    public Client() {
    }

    public Client(Integer id, Integer age, Integer numberofrentals, String name, String address) {

        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
        this.numberofrentals = numberofrentals;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Integer getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Integer getnumberofrentals() {
        return numberofrentals;
    }

    public void setnumberofrentals(int numberofrentals) {
        this.numberofrentals = numberofrentals;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Client client = (Client) o;

        if (age != client.age) return false;
        if (numberofrentals != client.numberofrentals) return false;
        if (!id.equals(client.id)) return false;
        if (!name.equals(client.name)) return false;
        return address.equals(client.address);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + age;
        result = 31 * result + numberofrentals;
        result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + address.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Client{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", numberofrentals=" + numberofrentals +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Movie:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="movie")
public class Movie  implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="numberofrentals", nullable=false)
    private Integer numberofrentals;

    @Column(name="director", nullable = false)
    private String director;

    @Column(name="year", nullable = false)
    private Integer year;

    public Movie() {
    }

    public Movie(Integer id, String name, Integer numberofrentals, String director, Integer year) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.numberofrentals = numberofrentals;
        this.director = director;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public void setDirector(String director) {
        this.director = director;
    }

    public Integer getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(Integer year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Integer getNumberofrentals() {
        return numberofrentals;
    }

    public void setNumberofrentals(Integer numberofrentals) {
        this.numberofrentals = numberofrentals;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Movie movie = (Movie) o;

        if (!id.equals(movie.id)) return false;
        if (!name.equals(movie.name)) return false;
        if (!numberofrentals.equals(movie.numberofrentals)) return false;
        if (!director.equals(movie.director)) return false;
        return year.equals(movie.year);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + numberofrentals.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + director.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + year.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Movie{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", numberofrentals=" + numberofrentals +
                ", director='" + director + '\'' +
                ", year=" + year +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And the rented class which is jsut normal right now:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="rented")
public class Rented implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id", nullable= false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="movieID", nullable = false)
    private Integer movieID;

    @Column(name="clientID", nullable = false)
    private Integer clientID;

    public Rented(Integer id, Integer movieID, Integer clientID) {
        this.id = id;
        this.movieID = movieID;
        this.clientID = clientID;
    }

    public Rented() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getMovieID() {
        return movieID;
    }

    public void setMovieID(Integer movieID) {
        this.movieID = movieID;
    }

    public Integer getClientID() {
        return clientID;
    }

    public void setClientID(Integer clientID) {
        this.clientID = clientID;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Rented rented = (Rented) o;

        if (!id.equals(rented.id)) return false;
        if (!movieID.equals(rented.movieID)) return false;
        return clientID.equals(rented.clientID);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + movieID.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + clientID.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Rented{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", movieID=" + movieID +
                ", clientID=" + clientID +
                '}';
    }
}
```

What do I really need to change? I need to give the Rented class a movie and a client? Between client and book it's a one to many relationship. A book can be rented only once, a client can rent multiple books. Do I have to keep lists somewhere or how would the rented class look like and what else do I have to change in the other 2?

Answer (score 0):

First you should change clientId in `Rented` class to `private client Client`.
Next you have to add annotation `@ManyToOne` for this field. Next you have tt do the same with field movieId.
And of course you have to change contructors, getters and setters.

Comment: Sure but would that be enough? Nothing changes in the other 2?

Comment: If you need access from Movie to list of Rented instances -> yes, but if you need only access fron Rented instance to Movie and client it is enough. If you need more informations you can read about unidirectional and bidirectional relations in hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Your mappings should look like the below (additional fields omitted). Always think in terms of objects and not entity fields.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="rental")
public class Rental implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id", nullable= false)
    private Integer id;

    //movie associated with this rental
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="movieID", nullable = false)
    private Movie movie;

    //client associated with this rental
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="clientID", nullable = false)
    private Client client;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="movie")
public class Movie  implements Serializable {

    //collection of rentals for this movie
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie")
    private Set<Rental> rentals;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="client")
public class Client implements Serializable {

    //collection of rentals for this client
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
    private Set<Rental> rentals;
}
```

This is a basic bi-directional one-to-many mapping which you can read more about here:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Example_of_a_OneToMany_relationship_and_inverse_ManyToOne_annotations

Comment: So my classes hold a set of rentals... Do I need to make functions for actually adding into those lists or what?

Comment: Yes. Create add/remove rental methods and do not allow the Collections to be modified directly. It is important to keep the in-memory model consistent . See here for example:http://stackoverflow.com/a/26220097/1356423