# Foreign Key for Multiple Properties in Spring JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpa

I've an existing Child Entity with Properties. Now, I want to add a foreign key constraint to two Properties of Child Entity in Parent Entity. Following is the **`SQL`**

```
CREATE TABLE parent( 
   parent_id1 int
   parent_id2 int
   CONSTRAINT parent_pk PRIMARY KEY (parent_id_1,parent_id_2);
);

CREATE TABLE child(

   c_id INT PRIMARY KEY,

   parent_id_1 int,
   parent_id_2 int,
   constraint fk foreign key(parent_id_1,parent_id_2) references parent(parent_id_1,parent_id_2)
);
```

I've the `Child` Entity as

```
@Entity
class Child implements Serializable {
    @Id
    Integer cId;
    Integer parentId1;
    Integer parentId2;
// Getters and Setters
}
```

```
// Parent Key
@Embeddable
class ParentPk {
    Integer parentId1;
    Integer parentId2;

    // Getters, Setters, Equals and Haschode
}


// Parent Entity
@Entity
class Parent{

   @EmbeddedId
   ParentPk pKey;

   // Getters and Setters
}
```

What I am looking for is, to add a One-Way relationship from Parent to Child as a `property` in `Parent`.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135911/multiple-foreign-keys-in-one-mapping-class-hibernatejpaspring if it is helpful

Comment: Thanks, but that is what I **cannot** do. I cannot change my Child Entity's fields as they are used all over the Application.

Comment: What is your question then?

Comment: @dassum, I am sorry, I modified the question. I realized it wasn't explaining the purpose.

Comment: @Times, Sorry, I modified the question. It was unclear, my bad.

Comment: What exactly is not working? can you post error messages/stacktrace in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using below solution:

```
// Parent Entity
@Entity
class Parent{

   @EmbeddedId
   ParentPk pKey;


   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id1",
                    referencedColumnName = "parent_id1"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id2", referencedColumnName = "parent_id2")
    }
    )
    private List<Child> Child;

   // Getters and Setters
}
```