# JPA 2 - persisting two different entities with FK constraints in a single transaction

Tags: java, database, jpa-2.0

I have a database which has tables Entity1 and Entity2. Entity2 has a coinstraint which relates it to Entity1 : a simple FK-PK relationship.

I would now like to insert a row into table Entity1, and insert a corresponding row into table Entity 2. This has to be done in a single transaction. My attempt is below:

```
EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "BankingPU" );
EntityManager em = emfactory.createEntityManager();

em.getTransaction().begin();

//--- insert a bunch of checks which determine the value of a bool var "successful" here

Entity1 e1 = new Entity1;
Entity2 e2 = new Entity2;

//set attributes of the entities

em.persist(e1);
em.persist(e2);


if(successful) em.getTransaction().commit(); else
    em.getTransaction().rollback();
```

If I proceed like so, an exception is thrown when committing:

`Query: InsertObjectQuery(banking.Entity2[ id=21 ])
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "Entity2" violates foreign key constraint "Entity2_fk"
  Detail: Key (id)=(21) is not present in table "Entity1".
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO Entity2 (id, attr2, attr3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]`

This message says that `Key (id)=(21) is not present in table "Entity1"`, even though it should be from the first persist. Is this because this is inside a transaction? How do I get around this?

Also, the call `INSERT INTO Entity2 (id, attr2, attr3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)` is incorrect, as the values have been set.

In short, what is the best way to persist two different entities with FK constraints in a single transaction?

The relevant parts of the entity classes:

```
public class Entity1 implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "Entity1 ")
private Entity2 entity2;

}


public class Entity2 implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)

@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@OneToOne(optional = false)
private Entity2 entity2 ;

}
```

Comment: Please show your entity classes. They should have a One-To-One or One-To-Many relationship, where one entity is defined as the owner of the relationship.

Comment: Is it the latter `persist` call or the `commit` call which is throwing the exception? In either case I suspect that a `flush` between the two `persist` calls may do the trick.

Comment: It's the commit. I tried flushing, but the same exception is being thrown. I have included the relevant parts of the entity classes in the post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to persist two entities with JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219099/how-to-persist-two-entities-with-jpa)

Comment: Two things seem strange to me. 1) Neither Entity1 nor Entity2 have the `@Id` annotation on their fields `id`. 2) The `em.persist(e2)` shouldn't be necessary at all because of the `CascadeType.ALL`. You might also have a look [here](http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.de/2014/05/onetoone-with-shared-primary-key.html) as a very short example on how to persist two related entities sharing the same primary key (if that was your intention)