# Mapping to a child table twice - @OneToMany & @ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to model a parent entity which has a collection of child entities (childHistory) and also a pointer to the last added child (currentChild)

```
class Parent {
    //unidirectional
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "current_child_id")
    private Child currentChild;

    //bidirectional
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Child> childHistory;

    public Parent() {
        currentChild = new Child(this);
        childHistory = new ArrayList<>();
        childHistory.add(currentChild);
    }

    public void add() {
        currentChild = new Child(this);
        childHistory = new ArrayList<>();
        childHistory.add(currentChild);
    }
}

class Child {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;
    public Child(Parrent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

I currently get an exception for transient entities when I try to save the Parent (and count on cascading to persist the children). I can't save the Parent beforehand since I init everything in the Parent ctor.

Warnings (that lead to exceptions...):

> WARN: HHH000437: Attempting to save one or more entities that have a
>   non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved
>   transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these
>   dependent entities. Unsaved transient entity: `([com.Parent#<null>])`
>   Dependent entities: `([[com.Child#<null>]])` Non-nullable
>   association(s): `([com.Child.entity])`

---

> WARN: HHH000437: Attempting to save one or more entities that have a
>   non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved
>   transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these
>   dependent entities. Unsaved transient entity: `([com.Child#<null>])`
>   Dependent entities: `([[com.Parent#<null>]])` Non-nullable
>   association(s): `([com.Parent.currentChild])`

Is there a way to model this correctly and have NOT NULL db column with hibernate.

EDIT: For a repro see this gist: https://gist.github.com/jlogar/2da2237640aa013f2cfbda33a4a5dc84

Comment: how do you save your entities

Comment: `em.persist(new Parent());`
I omitted a couple of details that are a given (id, entitymanager, ...)

Comment: can you share your service

Comment: I don't see the point... it's just your usual JEE application - hibernate, JPA...

Comment: "I don't see the point." The point is it will  clearly show the root cause of the issue which is that you have not set both sides of a bi-directional relationship prior to saving. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219099/how-to-persist-two-entities-with-jpa/26220097#26220097

Comment: I've updated the question with a gist to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is refering to saving transient entity, this means you are trying to save entity which has relation with a non managed entity, since your parent is cascading the onetoone child then the problem would be with childHistory, since this is a bidirectional relation it would make since to cascade the children also

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Child> childHistory;
```

Comment: not the issue - the error is not an NRE. Fixed in the question now.

Comment: I'll try to come up with a sample project. I couldn't resolve the issue no matter how I moved around the cascades.

Comment: the transient issue appears even with the cascade?

Comment: Cascading on the relationship child>parent will have zero effect when saving an instance of Parent.

Comment: so you try to save child?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with the following code:

```
@Entity
class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "current_child", referencedColumnName = "child_id")
    private Child currentChild;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Child> history = new ArrayList<>();

    Parent(ChildInfo childInfo) {
        currentChild = new Child(this, childInfo);
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "child_id")
    int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "subtype_id")
    private Parent parent;

    Child(Parent parent, ChildInfo info) {
        this.parent = parent;
        // initialize the rest of the object with ChildInfo
    }
}
```

The difference appears to be to how you specify the optional relationships. In my case, I could only specify that the parent to child relationship is required, not both. When I specified that the relationship is required for both sides, I also got an error.

This appears to be related to the order in which Hibernate inserts each item into the database. Here's the commands executed to insert the two entities:

```sql
Hibernate: insert into dbo.child (parent_id) values (NULL)
Hibernate: insert into dbo.parent (current_child) values (1)
Hibernate: update dbo.child set parent_id=1 where child_id=1
```

The child is inserted first with a `NULL` id, then the parent is inserted, with its current reference pointing to the child. The child is then updated using the parent's id.