# object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing (JPA-Hibernate)

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, orm

This is the parent object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cart")
public class Cart implements Serializable{

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id; 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cart", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CartItem> cartItems;

    ...
}
```

This is the child object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cart_item")
public class CartItem implements Serializable{

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;     

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cart_id", nullable=false)
    @JsonIgnore 
    private Cart cart;

    ...
}
```

With this image of the database, you can see that the field `CartItem.cart` has a foreign key to the table **cart**.

[image]

When saving a parent object I want to save its children as well.

The children object, before being saved, needs to know the parent's **id** (you can see `@JoinColumn(name="cart_id")` inside CartItem class). I suppose that the framework takes care of the **id** issue.

I get the error:

```
      SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with 
path [/webstore] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested 
exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved 
transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: 
com.depasmatte.webstore.domain.Cart] with root cause
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved 
transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: 
com.depasmatte.webstore.domain.Cart
```

How should I handle a problem like this?

Tank you guys

Comment: You handle it by letting the framework take care of it by means of cascades: https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/

Comment: Are you taking about  cascade = CascadeType.ALL applied on cartItems field inside Cart class? I already tried it, but I get the error org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.depasmatte.webstore.domain.Cart

Comment: For a bi-directional association you must set both sides as detailed in the referenced guide. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219099/how-to-persist-two-entities-with-jpa/26220097#26220097 With that in place everything will work as expected.

Comment: So now you are asking a totally different question @MDP. Same title, completely different error? Ask a new question to solve the new problem. Original error has been resolved.

Comment: Hi @AlanHay, haven't my classes a bidirectional association? I'm afraid I didn't really understand what it means. I thought that with OneToMany and ManyToOne I get a bidirectional association