# foreign key not getting inserted when hibernate one to one mapping is used

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two entites as follows

**user entity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GeneratedType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(Cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
    private UserAddressEntity addressEntity;
}
```

**user address entity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_address")
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserAddressEntity{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private UserEntity user;
}
```

I am saving user entity as follows in service class

```java
@Service
public class UserService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public void saveUser(){
        UserEntity userEntity=new UserEntity();
        UserAddressEntity userAddressEntity=new UserAddressEntity();

        //logic here

        userEntity.setAddressEntity(userAddressEntity);
        userRepository.save(userEntity);
    }
}
```

After saving entity **user_id** column is not being saved in **user_address** table. It's value is saved as null.I can't seem to find where the issue is.

**EDIT:**
I have added following to entities after answer referred in comments but I am getting this error

`Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GeneratedType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(Cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
    private UserAddressEntity addressEntity; 

    //added this
    public void setAddressEntity(UserAddressEntity addressEntity){
        if (!addressEntity.equals(this.addressEntity)){
            this.addressEntity=addressEntity;
            addressEntity.setUser(this);
        }

    }
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_address")
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserAddressEntity{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private UserEntity user;

    //added this
    public void setUser(UserEntity user){
        if (!user.equals(this.user){
            this.user=user;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to persist two entities with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219099/how-to-persist-two-entities-with-jpa)

Comment: In a bi-directional relationship you **must** ensure both sides are set correctly as outlined in the answer referenced above.

Comment: @AlanHay I am getting this error after trying above solution `Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)`

Comment: Because a calls b calls a calls b....Add checks to only call when required i.e. existing reference != specified reference.

Comment: @AlanHay I added the checks but still getting same error

Comment: Okay. Update your question with what you hav done.

Comment: Why do you have entities as private classes?

Comment: Sorry they are actually public. I mentioned wrong here.I edited them in question

Comment: Okay, setting both sides should fix the original issue. You can verify that by simply modifying you existing code. If, as expected,  it solves the problem then you will need to debug your refactoring  that attempts to encapsulate these operations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the relationship correctly in `UserService.saveUser()`:

```
 userEntity.setAddressEntity(userAddressEntity);
 userAddressEntity.setUser(userEntity);
```

Also, use regular getters/setters, no need to add logic there.

Comment: I have already tried this as mentioned by @Alan Hay in comments. This is giving following error `Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)`  which I mentioned in the edit

Comment: @harv3 I just run your code, above the EDIT section, no error at all.

Comment: yeah there is no error but user_id column is not getting inserted into user_address table which is original issue. After setting both address and user entity it is giving error

Comment: @harv3 Make a proof-of-concept project and post it on Github.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended/best way to map a @OneToOne is to use @MapsId. With that approach, you don’t need at all a bidirectional association.

I would advise you to take look at link below, there you have answer to your question with example how to save and map between objects.

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Only if he wanted to use shared identity. And even so he still needs to adddress the same issue: both sides of the relationship need to be set.

Comment: In his example, didn't he already set both side of the relationship ? Problem might be that he did not get primary key of UserAddressEntity and because of that he might get null

Comment: the primary key of userAddressEntity is being generated and also getting stored in table, only user_id is being stored as null

Comment: Can you confirm that user entity in userAddress object has userId set ?